# Why did these characters not notice this at the end of The Light Brigade?

Tags: time-travel, the-light-brigade

Just finished "[*The Light Brigade*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/40523931-the-light-brigade)" from Kameron Hurley. Enjoyed the read very much, especially how everything neatly closes. There's one detail at the end that nags at me though:

> When old Dietz travel back in time to Sao Paolo before the Blink, she's been through the war twice, so about 8 years in total based on the date of her first Mars jump ('05) and the date of her interrogation ('09) and she's been tortured by Norberg and co. while detained. Yet, Tomas and Vi have nothing to say about that when she shows up, they just act as if everything is normal. Did she change body with her young self? There's nothing to indicate she can do this.

Comment: A gentleman doesn't comment on a lady's age or appearance

Comment: @Valorum But as per a comic I saw on Netflix, that makes it perfectly fine to ask her what her weight is ..  lol

Comment: Perhaps they assumed her aged appearance was caused by hardship.